# Difference dos2Unix and python script

Tags: python, dos2unix

I have files to convert to Unix format. 
What would be the differences/issues that I could face choosing python conversion way :

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
text = open(filename, 'rb').read().replace('\r\n', '\n')
open(filename, 'wb').write(text)
```

instead of : *calling dos2unix Unix command in a subprocess* ?

Thanks !

Comment: Invalid encodings in the file would be one thing which could break your Python program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man dos2unix`:

> The Dos2unix package includes utilities "dos2unix" and "unix2dos" to
>   convert plain text files in DOS or Mac format to Unix format and vice
>   versa.
>
> In DOS/Windows text files a line break, also known as newline, is a
>   combination of two characters: a Carriage Return (CR) followed by a
>   Line Feed (LF). In Unix text files a line break is a single character:
>   the Line Feed (LF). In Mac text files, prior to Mac OS X, a line break
>   was single Carriage Return (CR) character. Nowadays Mac OS uses Unix
>   style (LF) line breaks.
>
> Besides line breaks Dos2unix can also convert the encoding of files. A
>   few DOS code pages can be converted to Unix Latin-1. And Windows
>   Unicode (UTF-16) files can be converted to Unix Unicode (UTF-8) files.

...

> -ascii
>       Convert only line breaks. This is the default conversion mode.

`dos2unix` thus can do more than converting line breaks, but default behavior is only that.

If your file is in wrong encoding, you would have to deal with it with `dos2unix` too.